# How to Ensure View is Removed After Animation on repeated touches

Tags: android, animation

On a touch event, a custom drawable view is created, added to the root view, so it is shown on screen, then I have a fade animation, to fade it away. It's all working, but not under stress!

When I repeatedly execute the touch event, such as 3 rapid touches within a second, the custom drawable is unexpectedly left on screen.

Why is this? I want it removed every time. Here's the code:

```
/*
 * Adds view and fades out
 */
public void fadeoutView(final View v){

        if (rootView != null) {
            rootView.removeView(v);
        }
        rootView.addView(v);

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Fadeout called");
        final Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Fadeout onAnimationStart t:" + System.currentTimeMillis());

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Fadeout onAnimationEnd t:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                if (v != null && rootView != null) {
                    rootView.removeView(v);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        fadeOut.setFillAfter(true); // Want to keep affect
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        fadeOut.setStartOffset(0);
        fadeOut.setDuration(500);
        if (v != null) {
            v.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        }
}
```

This is executed from within the UIThread within public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, this was resolved taking out the removeView in onAnimationEnd:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // No processing needed
}
```

I don't understand why removing the line of removing the view, has stopped the view being unexpectedly added. Any ideas?